# Summing hidden input fields depending on the state of a corresponding radio button, outputting to third field

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to sum the values of hidden fields, based on weather or not a user selects a certain value in a radio button group.

The function should trigger on the change of either radio button to update the sum.

The sum should appear in a input field of its own.

**My HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="No" />
<input type="hidden" value="750" id="i_1" />

<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="No" />
<input type="hidden" value="500" id="i_2" />

<input type="number" id="result" value="" />
```

**My jQuery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){                 
    $("input[name$='radio2'], input[name$='radio1']").change(function(){        

            if($("input[name$='radio2']").val()==Yes)
            {var n2 = $("#i_2").val();}else
            {var n2 = 0;    }   

            if($("input[name$='radio1']").val()==Yes)
            {var n1 = $("#i_1").val();}else
            {var n1 = 0;    }

        var n3 = parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2);
        $("#result").val(n3);
    });
    $("input[name$='radio2']").filter(':checked').change()
});
```

Currently nothing happens when I adjust the radios, and I have no errors in my console

[Here is a JSfiddle of my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/S59Rb/)

I am using jquery 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following fiddle with changed code as per your requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/VuNgJ/

I have changed the input function check to

```
if($("input:radio[name=radio2]:checked").val()=='1')
        {
            var n2 = $("#i_2").val();
        } else {
            var n2 = 0;
        }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You check what the value of the radio button but the function `.val()` return string.
You have to ask:

> if($("input[name$='radio2']").val()=='Yes')

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements should read as follows

```
if($("input[name='radio2']:checked").val() === "Yes")
```

I have updated your fiddle with working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/S59Rb/1/